# Cofinite topology and proving that the union of open sets is open

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

I'm trying to prove that the cofinite topology satisfies the axioms for a topology. Most proofs of this I've seen, when considering arbitrary unions, seem to just "throw out" empty sets or only consider a family of nonempty sets. I'd like to say "without loss of generality, assume that each $U_i$ is nonempty." Here is how I've phrased it:

> Let $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}$ be a collection of open sets in $X$. Without loss of generality, we can assume that each $U_i$ is nonempty; indeed, if $I' \subset I$ has the property that for every $i' \in I'$, $U_{i'} \neq \emptyset$, we have
> $$
> \bigcup\limits_{i \in I} U_i = \bigcup\limits_{i' \in I'} U_{i'},
> $$
> so an arbitrary union can be reduced to an indexing set for a nonempty family of open sets.

Is this argument sound? If so, I can write a similar argument to only consider the intersection of a nonempty family.

Comment: Yes, this argument is sound. It is good that you want to work out the details as you see them clarifying the situation/proof for you, but I would consider this particular step unnecessary, as it is a "triviality" (what is trivial for this or that person might differ). It is "clear" that only nonempty sets influence the union, so you might ignore them. Also for the intersection over a family, if one set in the family is empty, then the intersetion is of course empty, so it is easy to rule that case out (seperation by cases).

Comment: @Cornman This is very helpful, thank you. Is the same true if $I = \emptyset$? The union would be empty and the intersection all of $X$, so these are trivially open. I assume they're not treated most of the time for that reason.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you know about set-theoretic axioms and deductive logic,

you can simply start by defining $F$ jn the following way:

$F=\{y\in\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X))|\forall z\in y: (X-z)\;\text{is a finite set}\}$

The task would be to prove:

$\forall f\in F: (X-\cup f)\;\text{is a finite set}$

Here $\cup f$ means "the union of those sets which are elements of $f$". This is a special notation used in axiomatic set theory.